# Enabled method doesn't seem to work on my Game Object component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, game-development

I'm developing a game in Unity at the moment and I ran into some trouble. For the past 2 days I've been trying to get a slowdown powerup to work but trough various means but it everything that I tried doesn't seem to work.

I changed the code to the corroutine sugested since this already solved allot of problems and narrow down the issue:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;



public class ClockCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(SlowMoveSpeed());
            //this.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            Debug.Log("White Ball Sensed");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator SlowMoveSpeed()
    {
        Debug.Log("White Ball Sensed Twice");
        InteractControl.moveSpeed = 2f; // set slow speed
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // suspend the process for 5 seconds
        InteractControl.moveSpeed = 10f; // 5 seconds later, set speed back


    }



}
```

InteractControl script. I just found the reason why it doesn't seem to react to the corroutine calls:

```
public class InteractControl : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    GameObject target;
    Vector3 directionToTarget;
    public static int LevelStart = 0;
    //public GameObject[] Balls;
    Renderer m_Renderer;
    public static float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public void OnObjectSpawn()
    { 
        if (ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4 && LevelStart == 0) //If statement is causing the powerup from not generating non powerup activation problem. It is above the InteractControl.moveSpeed call in the hierarchy
        {
            moveSpeed = 10f;
        }
        //m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("White Ball");
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //Movement speed of all the obstacles and powerups
        MoveInteract(moveSpeed); //Method responsable for the movement of the obstacles and powerups, gets called at start
    }
    void MoveInteract(float moveSpeed) //Method responsable for the movement of the obstacles and stars
    {

        if (target != null)
        {
            if(ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4) //Determine when RedBall goes from going down in a straigh line to following white ball
            {



            directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed,
                                        directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);

               // Debug.Log(getMoveSpeed());
            }
            else
            {
                directionToTarget = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }


    }

}
```

Apparently the moveSpeed value in the if statement I just added takes presedence over the value changes I make to moveSpeed in my ClockCollision class.

Does anyone know how I can choose which value assignment of a static variable (in this case moveSpeed) takes presedence over the other

What should happen is that all the gameobjects that InteractControl is attached too should slow down to a velocity of the their rigidbody based on a moveSpeed value of 2f instead of the initial 10f and switch back to 10f after 5 seconds. However what actually happens is that they continue to have a the same velocity they had before the powerup was catched since the script Clocktime never gets enabled. The script itself does work(except for the fact that it doesn't switch back to 10f after 5 seconds) if update does manage to get executed however since I only want update to be executed in certain situations I need to be able to enable and disable it.

As you can see from the images below unless I missed something all my gameobjects and scripts are assigned and attached correctly in order for enabled to work:

[image: Trigger Gameobject assignment]
[image: Trigger presence in scene]
[image: Proof that The script ClockTime is disbaled]

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in what way is the enabled not working? it sounds like as frank has suggested that its never completing cos you restarted everything every frame.

Comment: It's not activating the script"ClockTime", and thus accesing the update method within when the compiler gets to Trigger.GetComponent<ClockTime>().enabled = true; And it does this regardless of the stopwatch being reset in update all the time. For example when I get rid of all the code in update and just write Debug.Log("Something"); it still doesnt manage to access the class

Answer (score 0):

As is stated in the comment above `Update()`, it is executed once **every frame**. So you create a new `StopWatch` every frame, that never has the chance to go up to 5 seconds because you check its elapsed time immediately after creating it. You should alter your code to only create a Stopwatch once, but check its elapsed time every `Update`. That will solve at least one of your problems.

Comment: Ok ok, thanks. Any idea how I could solve the issue regarding the enabled method not working?

Answer (score 0):

frankhermes is correct, this code

```
    InteractControl.LevelStart++;
    var stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
```

should go in Start().

However, I'd highly recommend using a Coroutine instead of the stopwatch. It's easier and more efficient. Unless I'm missing something, there shouldn't be an issue with having this all in one script. You'd do something like this:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("White Ball"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(SlowMoveSpeed());
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

IEnumerator SlowMoveSpeed() {
     InteractControl.moveSpeed = 2f; // set slow speed
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // suspend the process for 5 seconds
     InteractControl.moveSpeed = 10f; // 5 seconds later, set speed back
}
```

**EDIT**
The reason why it is still not working seems to be with this function:

```
void MoveInteract(float moveSpeed)
{
    if (target != null)
    {
        if(ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4)
        {
            directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed,
                                    directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            directionToTarget = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

This is called once at the beginning, setting the velocity for the rigidbody. However, when the moveSpeed is updated in the coroutine, this function is not called again.
I haven't dealt much with static functions, but you could try to create a `public static void` function that passes in moveSpeed and re-sets the rb.velocity to that move speed. You could call this function from the Coroutine.

Another option that would be much less efficient would be to update the rigidbody velocity every frame to equal the moveSpeed.

Personally, I'd probably use delegates and events. You might want to try this if a static method doesn't work.
http://www.unitygeek.com/delegates-events-unity/
I would create an event in ClockCollision, something like

```
public delegate void OnSpeedChange(float speed);
public static event OnSpeedChange onSpeedChangeDelegate;
```

You'd also have to call the delegate in the coroutine:

```
if(onSpeedChangeDelegate != null)
{
    onSpeedChangeDelegate(2f); // This invokes the delegate
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // suspend the process for 5 seconds
    onSpeedChangeDelegate(10f); // 5 seconds later, set speed back
}
```

Then in InteractControl I'd subscribe to the delegate like this:

```
void Awake(){
     ClockCollision.onSpeedChangeDelegate += UpdateSpeed;
}

//Don't forget to unsubscribe:
void OnDestroy(){
    ClockCollision.onSpeedChangeDelegate -= UpdateSpeed;
}

// Update the speed
void UpdateSpeed(moveSpeed)
{
        if(ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4)
        {
            directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed,
                                    directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            directionToTarget = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
        }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I can't guarantee that this code is error-free since I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks man. But I keep on having the same problem even when I use the corroutine method you sugest. It does access the coroutine tough but for some reason it is not able to change the value of InteractControl.moveSpeed. Eventough it used to be able to before

Comment: How is this set up? Are you still using two separate files?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to see the InteractControl script.

Comment: Yes thanks allot already. I added the script to my edit with all the information I have about the issue so far and no I'm not using the 2 seperate files anymore

Comment: Can you post the code for the `MoveInteract(moveSpeed);` function? I can't say for sure, but since that's called once, it could be part of the issue.

Comment: I just edited the code to include the moveInteract method

Comment: void MoveInteract is called every time a new instance of the object the script is attached too gets set to active. That's the way the OnObjectspawn function works. It's linked too my objectpooler and as such it is called every second. Since on ObjectSpawn is called every second.

Comment: Okay, if I'm understanding what you're saying and OnObjectSpawn is called every second, then this is a simple logic issue. You might just need a static boolean in interact control like `isSlowMotion` and set that where you are currently setting `moveSpeed`. Then in `OnObjectSpawn()` check if it is slow motion, and if so, set the speed to 2, otherwise use your initial condtion.

Comment: Okay, thanks man. It now is able to change the value of movespeed appropriatly however it now seems to only accept values for the parameter of WaitForSeconds of 2f or less. Anything more then that and it acts like waitforseconds is infinite. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I'm not sure. It probably has something to do with the logic or how the game is set up. It could also depend on when and how often you're getting the powerup. Since this issue has kind of changed from the original question, this might be a better question for the unity community: https://forum.unity.com/?_ga=2.97124831.1509099701.1565976142-878657027.1564169782